# C++ SysCall asm unresolved externals

Tags: c++, assembly, memory, ntdll

I am trying to call NtReadVirtualMemory via a syscall in asm. I am doing this for a few different reasons but it is not to important. So I define the function like so in my main header file:

```
extern "C" NTSTATUS SysWPM(HANDLE ProcessHandle, PVOID BaseAddress,
PVOID Buffer, ULONG NumberOfBytesToWrite, PULONG NumberOfBytesWritten);
```

The parameters I believe are correct

I then created an ASM file in the project. I only know enough about it to try and complete this task because it's a very small part of it. Supposedly you do not need to include this asm file anywhere so I left that. Here it is:

```
.code

SysWPM proc

    mov r10, rcx
    mov eac, 37h
    syscall
    ret

SysWPM endp

end
```

Now however when I compile, I get the unresolved external error. I believe this is because I need to define it within this ASM file but I am not sure how to go about doing it. What am I doing wrong/what should I do.

Thought it may be useful to mention I am on Windows 7 and the actual syscall index is 37 as shown in this table:

[table](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/ntapi_64/)

Here is the exact error for those asking:

```
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SysWPM referenced in function _main
1>c:\users\Reece\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\cs-ext\Debug\cs-ext.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

---

Still getting the error with the commented solution:

```
_SysWPM@20 proc

    mov r10, rcx
    mov eax, 37h ;
    syscall
    ret

_SysWPM@20 endp

extern "C" NTSTATUS NTAPI SysWPM(HANDLE ProcessHandle, PVOID BaseAddress,
PVOID Buffer, ULONG NumberOfBytesToWrite, PULONG NumberOfBytesWritten);
```

Comment: Can you show the exact error from the linker?

Comment: Also, how are you compiling the asm file?

Comment: This isn't how you do it. You don't use the `syscall` instruction in your own code. You just use a regular `call` to a function exported by NtDll.dll.

Comment: Make sure you export it from your asm file (e.g. `PUBLIC SysWPM` or `SysWPM proc PUBLIC`), and that you use the proper naming convention.

Comment: Thats exactly what I don't want to do. I am creating a program that uses no direct WINAPI calls or anything like that. If I wanted to get the function I'd have to use GetModuleHandle or i'd have to manually search for it which I do not want to do

Comment: `eac` this is your unresolved external ? `mov eac, 37h` when need `mov eax, 37h`. however you sure 37h ? you need got index in runtime, but never hardcode

Comment: Uhm... no. Just link against the respective library, ntdll.lib and ntdllp.lib. Besides, the error message showed you the **exact** symbol the linker is looking for. Just rename your ASM procedure name.

Comment: Can you explain what the point is in writing a *Windows application* that does not make calls to *Windows APIs*?

Comment: WINAPI functions hooked, want to work it so I don't use it and get logged

Comment: Apart from exporting you might need to prefix the name with an underscore as in the error message, or possibly declare it as `proc C`

Comment: what is error ?? print error message

Comment: you compile `c/c++` as x86 and `asm` as x64 ?!

Comment: I am compiling as x64

Comment: @Reece - are you sure ? `symbol _SysWPM referenced in function _main` - this is x86 mangling for __cdecl

Comment: if you got `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SysWPM` - 1) you compile and linking x86 code !!! 2) you declare `SysWPM` as `__cdecl` (default) when I say from begin - it must be `__stdcall` (`NTAPI`) - this I view even remote, when you can not view this local

Comment: If you are using VS, did you happen to add the MASM target to the project build dependencies so that it would assemble the ASM files? If you enable it after the fact you have to go back and mark your ASM file with an item type of "Microsoft Macro Assembler" rather than "Does not participate in build". If you create a new C++ app, MASM targets aren't enabled by default. They won't be assembled or linked.

Comment: If the above is possibly an issue, someone has some instructions on enabling what I was referring to at this link: https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.ca&sl=pt-BR&sp=nmt4&u=http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157916/assembly-e-c-com-visual-studio-2015-e-masm-x86-64&usg=ALkJrhi0z3T8BjxwgOLDOEa7UX1qG9pxCQ

Answer (score 2):

you need declare function in c/c++ as

```
extern "C" NTSTATUS NTAPI SysWPM(HANDLE ProcessHandle, PVOID BaseAddress,
PVOID Buffer, ULONG NumberOfBytesToWrite, PULONG NumberOfBytesWritten);
```

this is `__stdcall` function

and in `asm` for `x86` (`ml /c /Cp code32.asm` -> `code32.obj`)

```
.686p

.MODEL flat

_TEXT segment

_SysWPM@20 proc
...
ret 20
_SysWPM@20 endp
_TEXT ends
end
```

for `asm` x64 (`ml64 /c /Cp code64.asm` -> `code64.obj`)

```
_TEXT segment 
SysWPM proc

    ...
   ret
SysWPM endp


_TEXT ENDS

END
```

Comment: It is either 37 or 55 I will test both.  
I declared it how you said and am still getting the error

Comment: @Reece what error ? please exactly - I can not view this remote

Comment: Unresolved External. I don't even think the ASM file is being compiled into the program

Comment: @Reece `Unresolved External` - what is exactly name !?! are you understand that you need show this

Comment: @Reece wait, sorry, you build x86 or x64 ? - you naming for x86 but code is x64

Comment: x86. unresolved external symbol _SysWPM@20 referenced in function _main

Comment: @Reece but your asm is *x64* ? you compile it at all ??

Comment: *r10* and *rcx* certainly aren't x86 registers.

Comment: Sorry building as x64, makes no difference either way

Comment: @Reece - I make update, I was initially confused by `symbol _SysWPM referenced in function _main` - this is x86 mangling for __cdecl

Comment: Tried that solution along with any command line options and still it gives me the unresolved external error on the function def. Changed debug to release by accident. Any command line options you showed are not recognised

Comment: @Reece - again repeat and last time - if you say error - please say **EXACTLY - WHAT IS ERROR**

Comment: 1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SysWPM

Comment: That is the EXACT errror

Comment: @IInspectable - `r10 and rcx certainly aren't x86 registers` - yes of course, I not look at asm code good enough . but `symbol _SysWPM referenced in function _main` - this is certainly x86 mangling for *cdecl* by this I and initially confused

Comment: @Reece `unresolved external symbol _SysWPM referenced in function _main` - this ? again ask - you compile for x86 target ? if you declare `SysWPM` as I say - it will be `_SysWPM@20` for x86 and `SysWPM` for x64. but look like you not change own code in c file and link to x86 target

Comment: Well where should I go about it know

Comment: @Reece - fantastic ! who is compile and linking ? I or you ? you even don't know are you linking for x86 or x64 ? and again - you not add `NTAPI` (or `__stdcall`) to `c` file !!

Comment: @Reece - if you got `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SysWPM` - 1) you compile and linking x86 code !!! 2) you declare `SysWPM` as `__cdecl` (default) when I say from begin - it must be `__stdcall` (`NTAPI`) - this I view even remote, what you can not view local

Comment: @Reece - what you did ? and what error *after* this ? if still `unresolved external symbol _SysWPM ` - you are **nothing did**